# Can I upgrade from Ubuntu 12.10 to Lubuntu 13.04 directly?

Tags: upgrade, 13.04, lubuntu

I have  ubuntu 12.10 installed on mypc.
I'm thinking to upgrade to 13.04.

Now i'd like to take the opportunity also  to test lubuntu.
Should I first upgrade ubuntu, then install lubuntu or  can I directly run the:

> sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop

In other words,Will I get Lubuntu 12.10 (my current os version) or lubuntu 13.04(last available)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lubuntu desktop is layer over your Ubuntu. It is not a full Lubuntu experience. It will just install the apps and desktop environment of lubuntu. So your installation will contain all apps of lubuntu and standard ubuntu.

So installing `lubuntu-desktop` will not make it Lubuntu 13.04. It will be ubuntu 13.04 with lubuntu desktop.

So you can approach either way. Only thing is if you Upgrade to ubuntu 13.04 & then install `lubuntu-desktop`  you will save few MBs.

Another note: `lubuntu-desktop`  is a meta package. It actually contains what needs to be installed. Once installed, removing `lubuntu-desktop` will not remove the all the apps. So uninstallation will be not that easy.

Comment: Can you please clarify: Lubuntu aims at low-spec machines. If I have _"Ubuntu 13.04 with Lubuntu desktop"_ as you say, will it be of equal performance as a true Lubuntu?

Comment: I am not very sure if it will be equivalent to lubuntu (I guess it will not) but you main gain speed based on the desktop environment